# How to add fields for the registration form in ASP.net Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms

**If I want to add first name,last name fields for the already implemented registration from in asp.net web forms. What are the steps that i wanna follow.

---

And how can i add connection for the database using asp.net web forms

Thank you.**

Comment: your question is way [too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -2):

You can add new field:

```
<table class="auto-style1">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style2">First Name:</td>
                            <td class="auto-style3">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="fName" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="fName" ErrorMessage="* First name is required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style2">Last Name:</td>
                            <td class="auto-style3">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="lName" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
```

and you will have a submit button, so you can add this code to your submit button click event

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          con.Open();
          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into "YOUR TABLE NAME" (firstName, 
           lastName) values ('" + fName.Text + "', '" + lName.Text + "')", con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
 }

      }
```

Comment: Actually i entered this cord to add a field.But when i add this i got an error. 
        <div>
             <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="FirstName" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">First name</asp:Label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="First_Name" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName"
                    CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The first name field is required." />
            </div>

Comment: @CodeCaster I thought it's an ad, but it does relate to the answer.